# Visual Studio breakpoint : Where does the arrow point to when break

Tags: c++, visual-studio, breakpoints

When break in C++ in Visual Studio 2017, there is a curly arrow that point to the current execution point.

But when you check some up stream method in the call stack (i.e. double click any method in the call stack), the arrow always point to the next line of the currently executed method, like:

```
  FunctionBeingExecuted()
->//Next Line
```

I take this as a convention which is not a big deal. But now for many times I meet arrows that point to the function instead of the next line. So what should the arraw point at?

Begin at the breakpoint, up to some method A in the call stack, the curly arrow points at the line after the method executed, but from that method A up, all curly arrow points at the methhd executed.

BTW I found a bug like phenomenon in VS2019, please read the comment:

```
void func0000() {
    int i = 0;//set breakpoint here
}

void TestMisc() {
    func0000();
    int i = 0;//arrow point to here even on the second break...
    i++;
    func0000();
}
```

Comment: Your function `func0000` might have been optimized away. (Although that is not likely since you are on the debug version)

Comment: This problem occurs if the executable and the code are not in sync, i.e. if you change the code after you built it.

Comment: @Hawky I'v add i++ in func0000 and check disassembly, the inc instructions are there. And both call instruction are there.

Comment: Curly arrow points at return point... It is straight arrow that points at current execution point.

Comment: @user7860670 Make sure you know in the question there are only curly arrow, which points at line before the return point sometimes, I'm checking whether the reason is unsynced code/binary.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I've synced the binary with code now, still have the problem.

Comment: There got to be straight arrow somewhere. If these arrows point at unexpected locations (given that symbols are in sync with binary) then most likely you are debugging optimized build or have stack corruption (or both).

Comment: @user7860670 The answer is indeed "Curly arrow always point to the return point". When the curly arrow point to the function being executed, the reason is that the return point is the same line as the function....e.g. res=func(). In my case there is indeed to straight arrow, the main call all the way to the breakpoing.